# Practical Cost of Uncontended Thread Locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, thread-safety

*For a start, I should place emphasis on _completely uncontended_ thread locks in this subject. I'm well-aware of the very large cost of threads entering highly contended locks, being blocked and suspended and having to wait their turn with context switches and so forth. So I'm not really interested in the cost of contended locks quite as much.*

**"Cheap"?**

I've been repeatedly told that thread locks are *"really cheap"* when uncontended, only to find the contrary in practice when profiling. I suppose it depends on how we define *"really cheap"*.

So my request is for details that can help make me understand that cost of entering and exiting uncontended thread locks in more absolute terms, such as clock cycle ranges for various types of locks (could be somewhat theoretical), if it relates to memory access and caches, etc. I'm kind of a low-level coder but not quite at the machine/assembly level (trying to improve my knowledge there as much as I can).

For example, are the costs comparable to heap allocation with a general-purpose allocator? Some people consider that cheap, but I'd consider it among the most expensive things possible. Is it comparable to a branch misprediction? Does it vary wildly as with the case of a memory load which could be super cheap from a cache line but quite expensive for completely uncached DRAM access?

To preface, I want to make it clear that I'm not asking this in foresight, trying to obsess over micro-efficiencies of something I've yet to measure. To the contrary, I'm asking this in *hindsight* after spending many years working in large-scale production codebases where I've frequently headbutted uncontended thread locks as actually being, far more often than I would expect, a major hotspot. So I want to understand the performance a bit better in a more absolute and accurate sense, particularly to help me relate to the costs better in terms of design decisions.

Also my standards for what constitutes "cheap" might be quite high, as I'm usually the one working inside data structures. For example, many seem to consider a heap allocation relatively cheap, and I'd agree if we're allocating handles to whole data structures. If we're inside a data structure and paying that overhead for every single element we insert to it, it can get enormously expensive. So my idea of "expensive" and "cheap" may be quite different.

**Bizarre Code**

One of the codebases I worked in had a very long legacy (decades). So it was largely designed to only work single-threaded with a lot of practices that made even a lot of basic functions not thread-safe (often not even reentrant). Some of the more ambitious developers there wanted to make that codebase increasingly multithreaded in a retrofitted way, and of course we ran into many horrible issues. Team response: sprinkle thread locks all over the place as the bugs come flooding in.

I was one of the few using profilers at the time, and constantly ran into hotspots revolving around thread locks which were still being used only in a completely single-threaded, uncontended context. Initially the codebase was using platform-specific code for it, and given that I was primarily using Windows for development/testing/profiling, the locks were native critical sections used by the windows API. Later we started using Qt to reduce portability headaches, and the critical section hotspots got replaced by bottlenecks in `QMutex`. Then later we started incorporating some of Intel's Thread Building Blocks, and I saw some hotspots in `tbb::mutex` (though not quite as many, but I'm not sure if it was because we didn't use it so much or if it was more efficient than the former two solutions: this was a *massive* codebase spanning in the many millions of lines of code).

And here's the gross part. I once pointed out a major bottleneck being in a `QMutex` lock which was completely uncontended. It was only being used in a single-threaded context, and the lock was just for thread-safety in case it was ever used in a multithreaded context. So my co-worker "optimized" it like this (pseudocode):

```
if (thread_id != main_thread_id)
     mutex.lock();
...
if (thread_id != main_thread_id)
     mutex.unlock();
```

And that actually eliminated our hotspot and significantly improved the performance, enough to make the user who reported the slowdown quite pleased with the results! Yet I think I vomited in my mouth a little bit when I saw that. It was based on an assumption that this was safe since it was in code reading a resource that could only be modified from the main thread.

This is where I most began to wonder about the true expense of uncontended thread locks, when code as weird as the above exchanging thread ID access and branching could actually eliminate significant real-world bottlenecks.

So my ultimate question is, how expensive is an uncontended thread lock exactly (or at least somewhat more exact than "it's cheap")?

In the cases I was seeing, if I go by intuition (with full realization that it could be totally wrong), I'd say the locks we were dealing with "felt" like they were in the 100-cycles kind of uncached DRAM access-like range (not quite as expensive as a malloc, but approaching there). Since people were interested in hardware/OS details, I'm generally interested in the broad answers since we're always dealing with multi-platform projects, but perhaps my specific interest would be the x86/x64, Windows, OSX, and Linux.

Comment: Which threading library on which O/S?...

Comment: @Joe Potentially all -- I'm completely interested in more theoretical-side answers assuming somewhat ideal implementations, or 'average', or ones specific to a particular hardware. Though I tend to work most on Windows myself (but the codebases often target OSX and Linux in addition), and most of my profiling sessions have been there. We've used everything from OS API calls to Qt's QMutex to the various flavors of locks provided by Intel's TBB.

Comment: I guess should also add - what hardware!?

Comment: x86/x64 would be my primary interest just given that it dominates the desktop market, and I'm usually working in desktop software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW: if everything is implemented optimally, mutex can be implemented, AFAIR, as two atomic increments/decrements (Interlocked*() function in Windows-speak); these in turn are translated (on x86) into asm operations with LOCK prefix, causing bus lock.

Bus lock, in turn, is implemented quite differently and MIGHT behave quite differently on single-socket-single-core, single-socket-multi-core, multi-socket-with-FSB, and NUMA/SUMO machines. In practice, though, I've seen the numbers around 100 clocks for multi-socket, and in dozens of clocks for single-socket. NB: these are EXTREMELY rough numbers, don't take them as granted until you perform your own measurements (on exactly the target hardware) using something like RDTSC.

P.S. The snippet you provided (with if(thread_id != main_thread_id)) is potentially unsafe even if the data can be modified only from within the main thread.

Comment: Many thanks for the response! The 100-clock cycle range seems to match what I was seeing. At least, given my somewhat intuitive sense of how instruction costs relate to clock cycles (though my intuitions could be quite wrong with complex pipelines and so forth), the hospots "felt" like they were in the 100-cycle kind of range -- not quite as expensive as a memory allocation (which I'd say "feels" like few hundred cycles). About the code being unsafe, it seemed that way to me as well, though I couldn't articulate why.

Comment: Side question: how do we determine clocks anyway with any degree of accuracy? I'm often just looking at measurements of use cases in profilers, possibly some timing tests (but they're usually too high-level and too real world to narrow down the clock cycles reported to specific micro-level details). The only way I know to do is to look up the assembly instructions involved from a disassembly, and even then I'm always confused with pipelining. So I've gotten somewhat of a "feel" for how things cost roughly that seems reasonably correct, but have never been able to get that precise.

Comment: On x86, RDTSC is the best way to find out clocks, as far as I know. Note of caution: on some multi-socket machines RDTSC might be highly misleading (if it is not properly initialized by motherboard, RDTSC counters won't be exactly synchronized between different sockets).

Comment: @TeamUpvote: "About the code being unsafe, it seemed that way to me as well, though I couldn't articulate why." - when you have your main thread manipulating your data (such as a list or something), it can be easily in a temporarily-inconsistent state, so if other thread (which will obtain lock successfully, as there is nobody holding the mutex) will try to read that temporarily-inconsistent data - everything can easily crash.

Comment: @No-BugsHare If the invariant you stated about the main thread is really true, then the code doesn't need a mutex for safety, just an assertion that it is being called from the main thread.

Comment: @Tim Seguine: depends on how exactly to understand it. If we have a guarantee that all _accesses_ (including read-only ones) are from main thread only - sure, assert is enough. However, if (as I meant) it is only writes which are restricted to the main thread, and reads can be done from elsewhere - there is nothing easier than to get an access violation in this reading thread due to temporary inconsistencies in the data being read. Try heavy modifications to std::list<> in one thread, while traversing it in the other one.

Comment: @No-BugsHare the situation you described is a data race, unless you are just explaining it awkwardly. You are leaving off taking the lock in exactly the thread that is doing all the writing. There is nothing to force the "happens before" relationship required between conflicting memory accesses.

Comment: @Tim Seguine - sure, it is a data race; my point is that when replacing locks with asserts, one has to be very careful to avoid this kind of races (and the claim of "all _writes_ are done from one single thread" is not sufficient to guarantee safety).

Comment: @No-BugsHare It seems like you understand the issues. I am now just confused as to why I was trying to convince you of anything.